# Big Query to TF Record

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, apache-beam, tfrecord

My Goal is validate my data in BQ using tensorflow-data-validation for my machine learning environment. So as a first step I am trying to generate tfrecord file from result of my BQ Query.

I am trying to do this using Apache-Beam. But there is some problem with encoding.

```
 **Apache-Beam Code**     
(pipeline | 'Read Input Data' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
    query=input_query,
    use_standard_sql=True,
    coder=coders.BytesCoder()
))
 | 'Generate TF Record' >> beam.io.WriteToTFRecord('path/to/output/',
   coder=coders.BytesCoder(),                                                   
   file_name_suffix='.tfrecord.gz'))

**Tensorflow-Data-Validation-Code:**
tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(
    data_location='path/to/output/',
    pipeline_options=pipeline_options
)
```

The error thrown is **DecodeError: Error parsing message [while running 'DecodeData']**. Could some please help me in solving this

Comment: Any chance you can share if you figured out how to read a bigquery table into a TF Record? I am finding examples with transforms but just want a simple import into a TF Record.